# Подключение JS к WebView

Tags: android, webview

Есть страница со структурой

```
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Как мне в браузере скрыть `<div id="header"></div>` и всё, что внутри него?

```
   public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsById(header).style.display = 'none'; ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lichkab);
        //


        //
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://tetrapolis.handybank.ru/");
        //mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться функцией evaluateJavascript?

Почитать документацию? :-D

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Правда есть нюанс - это для кит ката только.

Для более ранних версий, я думаю, надо выкачивать html, добавлять туда скрипт, и отдавать уже во вьюху.

Comment: Посмотреть в коде, который я выложил, что у меня вставлен js, который почему-то не отрабатывает - не, не слышал. :-D

Comment: Так и не должен же, вы же его ссылкой передаёте, я вот сильно не уверен, что веб вьюха обязана такое хавать.
_____
Хотя попробуйте тогда кавычки поставить
 
    "javascript:document.getElementsById(->'<-header->'<-).style.display = 'none'; "

Вдруг проканает, и у Вас просто опечатка в js'e. :-)

Comment: @Чад К сожалению, не опечатка, но когда я так делаю, страница загружается - и после полной загрузки пропадает, и появляется просто надпись none. Т.е. если я напишу `.style.display = 'none22';`, то появится надпись none22. Но блок header всё равно не скрывается, а пропадает страница.

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, Ну тогда делайте, как я написал: или используйте функцию evaluteJavascript, но это только для кит ката, или грузите Html-ку в переменную, дописывайте туда `<script ...> document.getElem...</script>` и загружайте не по урлу, а по контенту.

Answer (score 0):

Скрывать блоки по окончание загрузки стр. выглядит не очень красиво, если и скрывать то уже начиная со старта страницы, я для этого использовал WebChromeClient

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
{ 
    if (progress < 100) {
        wv.loadUrl("javascript:какой то скрипт");
    }
}
```

Собственно так делаю когда не вижу больше выхода, а так лучше будет подменять css сайта свой.

**UPD**

По поводу js, почему бы не использовать

```
$('#header').attr('style', 'display:none');
```